# Find the ratio between each column entry and the following entry, for every column, for a list of data.frames in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this, where there are ~500 dataframes in a list:

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
```

Within each column, I want to find the ratio of the first value to the second value, then the third value to the fourth, then the fifth value to the six, etc. Then I want to do that to every column, and output it to a new data frame. Like this:

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.5                         
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.5
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.5
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.5
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.5
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.5 
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.5
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.5
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.5                         
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.5
```

And I want to be able to apply it to the list of data frames at one time.

The closest I've gotten is with one data frame, and only one column... where I would also have to delete every other value (which is ok, I can do that in post processing).

```
ratio = df[[1]][,1]/lag(df[[1]][,1],1)
```

But again, it needs to do every column into the new data frame, applied to a list of data frames.

Note that the actual values can be anything from 0 to 2000, they are not necessarily all 1's and 2's.

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, rep(1:2, 10)))
ll <- list(df, df, df)
```

Comment: does this work if `ll` is your list of data frames? `lapply(ll, function(x) x[c(TRUE, FALSE), ] / x[c(FALSE, TRUE), ])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `apply` function, and work with the `seq` function. The key is in what we're doing with the `seq` function. The first one we're iterating from 1 to n by steps of 2 (1, 3, 5, ...), the next we're iterating from 2 to n by steps of 2 (2, 4, 6, ...). This might cause issues if your row count is not an even number.

```
apply(d, 2, 
      FUN = function(x) x[seq(1, length(x), by = 2)] / x[seq(2, length(x), by= 2)])

      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8  V9
 [1,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.5
 [2,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.5
 [3,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.5
 [4,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.5
 [5,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.5
 [6,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.5
 [7,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.5
 [8,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.5
 [9,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.5
[10,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.5
```

Using the list you added to your question:

```
lapply(ll, 
       FUN = function(d) 
           apply(d, 2, 
                 FUN = 
                     function(x) x[seq(1, length(x), by = 2)] / x[seq(2, length(x), by= 2)]))
```

Comment: This isn't working, please let me know if I'm implementing it incorrectly.                     
 ratios<-apply(df, 2, FUN = function(x) x[seq(1, length(x), by = 2)] / x[seq(2, length(x), by= 2)])
Error in apply(df, 2, FUN = function(x) x[seq(1, length(x), by = 2)]/x[seq(2,  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length                               
df[[1]][seq(1, length(df[[1]]), by = 2)] / x[seq(2, length(df[[1]]), by= 2)]
Error in Ops.data.frame(df[[1]][seq(1, length(df[[1]]), by = 2)],  : 
  ‘/’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
dim(df[[1]])
[1]  20 102 (I posted a subset)

Comment: `apply` is meant for each individual data.frame in your list. We can loop through your lists using `lapply`. See my edit.

Comment: Using your updated code with lapply I am getting the following error: Error in apply(d, 2, FUN = function(x) x[seq(1, length(x), by = 2)]/x[seq(2,  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: However it works in a single data frame using this code: test<-apply(df[[1]], 2,FUN = function(x) x[seq(1, length(x), by = 2)] / x[seq(2, length(x), by= 2)]), and when I run it on any random selection of a single data frame

Comment: Confirming the code works fine, though it does change the data.frame to a matrix. Easily changed by replacing `apply(d, 2, FUN)` with `data.frame(lapply(d, FUN))` however.

Comment: I'm getting the same error still. It does work fine on individual data.frames but not on the whole set. Using the original code error is the same, using the change proposed by thelatemail error code is:  Error in seq.default(2, length(x), by = 2) : wrong sign in 'by' argument

Comment: I'll comment that it has to be agnostic to what the actual numbers are - in the example they are all 1's and 2's but they can be anything in the dataset (not negative, but they can be zero). My apologies that the example is not entirely representative.

Comment: The only way I can get that result is if you have a data.frame in your list that has 0 rows or 1 row giving essentially `seq(1,0,2)`. And if that's the case, then your intended calculation won't work. You'd have to add an `if` + `else` to account for those cases - 
`lapply(ll, function(d) 
  if(nrow(d) > 1)
    data.frame(lapply(d, function(x) x[seq(1,length(x),2)]/x[seq(2,length(x),2)])) else
    d
)`

Comment: Thank you thelatemail. Yes, it does appear that there is probably an issue with OP’s data. @user2472414, can you confirm that all of your data has row count >= 2?

Comment: No, but I did have one data frame with only two rows. Removing this has made it work.